# AVPlayer synchronised with UISlider in iOS

Tags: ios, queue, uislider, avplayer

Working on an app in iOS , I am playing a video using AVPlayer and i am synchronising the slider with the playerItem current duration using:

```
//synchronizing the current time label and slider with the player.
[self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 100) queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time)

{
    CMTime endTime = CMTimeConvertScale (self.player.currentItem.asset.duration, self.player.currentTime.timescale, kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero);
    if (CMTimeCompare(endTime, kCMTimeZero) != 0) {
        double normalizedTime = (double) self.player.currentTime.value / (double) endTime.value;
        self.slider.value = normalizedTime;
    }
    Float64 currentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime);
    int mins = currentSeconds/60.0;
    int secs = fmodf(currentSeconds, 60.0);
    NSString *minsString = mins < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", mins] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mins];
    NSString *secsString = secs < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", secs] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secs];
    self.currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", minsString, secsString];
}];
```

The problem is that i am playing the video in Modal view, when I press the button to dismiss the view controller, the view controller dismisses but the video keep on playing in the background(as the audio of the asset can be heard). How can i solve that? I am sure that it has to do with the queue I am using, but i have tried both the main queue and the concurrent queue, but every time, results are same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stop `AVAssetReader` by calling `cancelReading` method on it.

Doc:

> cancelReading
>
> Cancels any background work and prevents the receiver’s
>   outputs from reading more samples.
>
> - (void)cancelReading Discussion If you want to stop reading samples from the receiver before reaching the end of its time range, you
>     should call this method to stop any background read ahead operations
>     that the may have been in progress.

Also you should use `removeTimeObserver` method of `AVPlayer` when you dismiss modal view.

There is also `pause` method of AVPlayer if you don't have `AVAssetReader`.

Comment: What should be the parameter observer in "removeTimeObserver:(id)observer"?

Comment: It must be the return value from your call to `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:`

Comment: How can i get the value returned by the method addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock: in above mentioned code?

Comment: If that's viewController where you call `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` you can keep it in `@property (strong, nonatomic) id periodicObserver`. Then call `self.periodicObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval...` and later do `[self.player removeTimeObserver:self.periodicObserver];`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine for resetting the slider value, but still the problem is there, that the video keeps on playing even after dismissing the view controller.

Comment: How do you stop video playback?

Comment: I am not, its just a small video, which stops with the dismissing of view controller or it stops when it reaches the end as i am using [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkPlayEnded) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.playerItem];

Comment: Actually it was working fine before i was using this addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:

Comment: How do you dismiss your view controller, what do you do when it's dismissed?

Comment: I am dismissing it using: [[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Actually, in this view, i want to merge any number of videos. Once they are merged, i am playing them using AVPlayer, and if the user is satisfied with the video, he can upload the video by pressing the upload button in the view. I am able to join the videos, during playback, if i press the back button, the view controller is dismissed but video keeps on playing. I encountered this issue once I added addPeriodicTimeObserverFor..... for synchronising the slider with the play back

Comment: I think this all happens because when you create block it retains self which is viewController in your case, so even you dismiss it, it is still there and not released (dealloc is not called). This is actually strange because I would think when you call removeTimeObserver it should be released from the block and finally it should be gone. Anyway I think you should stop the playback manually.